# I'm trying to redirect /example to example.html in Apache's httpd.conf, but it doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Here's the code I'm trying to apply in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com

    DocumentRoot /home/test_com
    ErrorLog /home/logs/apache/www_test/www.test.com-error_log
    CustomLog /home/logs/apache/www_test/www.test.com.-access_log common env=!do_not_log

    # https redirect
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.test.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /example
    RewriteRule . https://www.test.com/example.html [R=303,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}

    <Directory "/home/test_com/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

After applying the code and restarting apache, when I go to /example I get a 404 not found response.

When I test htaccess at (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be), the output is as https://www.test.com/example.html as I want. I wonder what the problem is.

Comment: Are you making the request over HTTP or HTTPS? All your directives are in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` container and you are redirecting to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.test.com
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /example
> RewriteRule . https://www.test.com/example.html [R=303,L]
> ```
>
> when I go to /example I get a 404 not found response.

Not sure if something has been lost in your exemplification, but from the rules as written, if you request `/example` it will result in a redirect-loop as it will continually redirect to `/example.html` again and again. (Unless you are actually making the request over HTTPS, in which case the directive isn't doing anything at all and you will indeed get a 404!)

This is because the second *condition* `%{REQUEST_URI} /example` also matches the target URL `/example.html`. You need to make the regex more specific and match only `/example`, not any URL that simply contains `/example`. This check can also be moved to the `RewriteRule` directive (the *condition* is not required). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/example$ https://www.test.com/example.html [R=303,L]
```

The condition that checks the `HTTP_HOST` would not seem necessary, since these directives are in the vHost for `www.test.com`, so it cannot be any other hostname?

However, since this rule is in the vHost for port 80, it is only going to apply to HTTP requests (not HTTPS). If you are actually requesting `https://www.test.com/example` (ie. HTTPS) as would seem to be implied by your test results from the MWL tool, then the directive is never going to be processed and you will indeed get a 404.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}
> ```

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is missing the last part so redirects everything to the homepage. The `RewriteRule` directive should read:

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

However, there's no point redirecting to HTTPS if all your directives are in the vHost:80 container.

This rule is also more complex than it needs to be. Since you are in the vHost:80 container, `HTTPS` is always going to be `off` - the check is redundant.

---

> ```
> ServerName www.test.com
> ServerAlias www.test.com
> ```

If you only have one hostname then you don't need two directives. Only the `ServerName` is required in this case.

---

> When I test htaccess at (`https://htaccess.madewithlove.be`)

You don't have an `.htaccess` file here. You are using the directives directly in the vHost container, which is a different *context*. The directives behave slightly different here. For example, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `.` (a single dot) has a different result here than when used in `.htaccess`. In a *virtualhost* context it is successful for *every* request, whereas in `.htaccess` it is successful for everything *except* the homepage (which is probably the intention here).

However, the MWL `.htaccess` tester only makes a "single" request (or single pass through the file). It does not "follow" redirects or make multiple passes through the file as it would do in a real server environment. So it cannot catch redirect/rewrite loops - which are a common cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

The right part on RewriteRule is **the destination file**, try change :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /example
```

To :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /example.html
```

Comment: Although this would make it even _more_ wrong! The OP is wanting to redirect to `/example.html`. The _condition_ you have proposed a change to would check that the request is already `/example.html` (except this is a regex) before redirecting to `/example.html`. Using `/example` is in the right ballpark - except, as mentioned, this is a regex so matches way too much (it needs to be more restrictive so that it _only_ matches `/example`). Unfortunately, there are several other issues with the OPs code that would also prevent this from working as intended.